# How to toggle a boolean field by sql in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

There is a field `show` which is a `boolean` type in postgesql.

I want to write a sql to update that table, to toggle the value of show. If it's `true`, it becomes `false`, if it's `false`, it becomes `true`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This will do:

```
SET show = NOT show
```

so a value of

`TRUE` becomes `FALSE`,

`FALSE` becomes `TRUE`,

`UNKNOWN` (`NULL`) stays `UNKNOWN`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yeah, but I had to write something to cover the 30 characters limitation. Since we already had `TRUE` and `FALSE`, a variation on `UNKNOWN` was appropriate :)

Comment: This is awesome, elegant, and exactly what I wanted. Ultra glad this isn't only possible MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

The following will turn `FALSE` or `NULL` to `TRUE`, and `TRUE` to `FALSE`:

```
UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = NOT COALESCE( fieldname, 'f' ) WHERE keyvalue = ?;
```